# Probability of that a number from a set is in a subset

Tags: probability-theory

Say you have a set of 40 numbers from which you draw a set of 6 unique numbers initially while replacing the removed values. What is the probability that a number drawn at random from the set of 40 numbers is in the set of 6 numbers ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the 40 numbers are unique, and after drawing the 6 unique numbers, they are replaced: then the probability of drawing one number from the 40 unique numbers such that the drawn number matches one of the six unique numbers is: $$\dfrac{6}{40} = \dfrac{3}{20} = .15\;\;\text{ or}\;\;15\%$$

Comment: Does this make sense, cobie?